# Powershell stream events

Tags: powershell, runspace

I wonder if it's possible to subscribe to the current Powershell session event stream so that every time some information/warning/error etc is added to the stream I can read it as an object. I was able to subscribe to `DataAdded` events of the 3 streams mentioned above, but for some reason I can intercept events only from `error stream`

```
$InformationPreference = 'Continue'

$ps = [PowerShell]::Create("CurrentRunspace")
$ps.Streams.Information.Add_DataAdded({
     # THE EVENT IS NEVER TRIGGERED
    $ps.Streams.Information.ReadAll().ForEach{ 
        Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)
    }
})
$ps.Streams.Warning.Add_DataAdded({
    # THE EVENT IS NEVER TRIGGERED
    $ps.Streams.Warning.ReadAll().ForEach{ 
        Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)
    }
})
$ps.Streams.Error.Add_DataAdded({
    #WORKS FINE
    $ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll().ForEach{ 
        Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)
    }
})

$ps.AddScript({
    Write-Information 'Some Information'
    Write-Warning 'Some Warning'
    Write-Error 'Some Error'
}).Invoke()
```

Any ideas why Warning and Information streams don't trigger events?

Comment: What is the purpose behind this? PowerShell already provides native mechanisms for redirecting any stream (except progress stream), e. g. `& { Write-Information 'Some Information'; Write-Warning 'Some Warning'; Write-Error 'Some Error' } *>&1 | Out-String -Stream`

Comment: @zett42 The idea is to stream output to WebApplication in realtime, once a message arrives I need to display it. The mechanism you mentioned almost fits my needs, but the problem is that all the messages are just strings and it's not possible to tell Debug message from Information for example.

Comment: You can differentiate them while they are still objects: `... *>&1 | ForEach-Object { if( $_ -is [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] ) { "ERROR: $_" } }`. If you like I can write a more complete example as an answer.

Comment: @zett42 Yes, you are right! It's a much simpler/better way to achieve what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Similar code here seems to work... The only significant difference seems to be the output is added to collection instead of written to host.  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7477#issuecomment-411596046

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to redirect all streams of a script block to the success stream, keeping the original formatting intact and still be able to **differentiate the kind of stream**.

```sh
& {
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Foo = 42; Bar = 23 } | Format-Table  # Output
    $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
    Write-Debug 'Some Debug'
    Write-Information 'Some Information'
    Write-Warning 'Some Warning'
    Write-Error 'Some Error'

} *>&1 | ForEach-Object -PV record { $_ } | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object {
    # Process a single line of formatted output

    $prefix = switch( $record ) {
        { $_ -is [Management.Automation.DebugRecord] }       { 'DBG'; break }
        { $_ -is [Management.Automation.InformationRecord] } { 'INF'; break }
        { $_ -is [Management.Automation.WarningRecord] }     { 'WRN'; break }
        { $_ -is [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] }       { 'ERR'; break }
        default                                              { 'OUT' }
    }

    # Prepend prefix and output current line 
    "[$prefix] $_"  
}
```

**Output:**

```text
[OUT]        
[OUT] Foo Bar
[OUT] --- ---
[OUT]  42  23
[OUT]        
[OUT]
[DBG] Some Debug
[INF] Some Information
[WRN] Some Warning    
[ERR] 
[ERR]   [PSCustomObject]@{ Foo = 42; Bar = 23 } | Format-Table  # Output
[ERR]   Write-Debug 'Some Debug'
[ERR]     Write-Information 'Some Information'
[ERR]     Write-Warning 'Some Warning'
[ERR]     Write-Error 'Some Error'
[ERR]
[ERR]  : Some Error
[ERR] In ***\RedirectAllStreams.ps1:1 Char:1
[ERR] + & {
[ERR] + ~~~
[ERR]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
[ERR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
[ERR]
```

**Remarks:**

- `*>&1` [redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2#powershell-redirection-operators) (merges) all streams (except progress) into the success (aka *stdout*) stream
- `ForEach-Object -PV record { $_ }` - stores the current stream *object* into variable `record`, by using common parameter [`-PipelineVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3#-pipelinevariable) (`-PV`) and forwards it to the next command
- `Out-String -Stream` - converts the current stream *object* into a stream of strings (one string for each line of output), to make sure PowerShell's formatting system is honored (for instance, the `Format-Table` example wouldn't work without this).
- The final `ForEach-Object` processes only strings, but the type of stream object is still available through variable `$record`, so we can use the `-is` operator to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I got. Looks like it is working. I just copied you code and posted into powershell.

[image]

Comment: Not quite... The output you see comes from script execution, not from event handlers. If you change `Write-Host ($_ | Out-String)` to `($_ | Out-String) | Out-File -Path ...`, then only `Write-Error` content will appear in the file

Comment: Are you an Admin?  Did you start powershell by right click on shortcut and select Run As Admin?  Do a websearch for "powershell categoryinfo not specified"